# Display html content of webview in custom font in android

Tags: android

I have a HTML content below displaying in a webview

```
<p><a href="https://www.google.com"><cite>Here</cite></a></p>
```

How to apply a custom font(`.ttf file`) that i have in assets folder

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'myFont';
   src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/myCustomFont.ttf'); 
}
```

In body, you can use

```
body { 
   font-family: 'myFont', serif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
WebView webview = findViewById(R.id.webView1);
String start = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: MyFont;src: url(\"YOUR CUSTOM FONT ASSET HERE")}body {font-family: MyFont;font-size: medium;text-align: justify;}</style></head><body>";
String end = "</body></html>";
String mHtmlString = start + "<p><a href="https://www.google.com"><cite>Here</cite></a></p>" + end;
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,mHtmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```